# Grunt copy plugin not able to configure

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-copy

I'm new to grunt and for my project I'm using grunt-contrib-copy plugin.My folder structure is:

[image]

```
module.exports = function(grunt){

const sass = require('node-sass');
require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

grunt.initConfig({
    sass: {
        options: {
        implementation: sass,
    }, 
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: 'sass',
          src: ['*.scss'],
          dest: 'assets/css',
          ext: '.css'
        }]
      }
    },

    cssmin: {
        target: {
          files: [{
            expand: true,
            cwd: 'assets/css',
            src: ['*.css', '!*.min.css'],
            dest: 'build/assets/css',
            ext: '.min.css'
          }]
        }
      },

      copy:{
          html:{
              files:[{
                  expand:true,
                  dot:true,
                  cwd:'components',
                  src:['**/*.html'],
                  dest:'build/'
              }]
          }
      }
  });



  grunt.registerTask('default', ['sass','cssmin','copy']);
}
```

I want to copy the index.html and the components folder to the build folder but I'm not able to configure it. I'm able to copy either the index.html file or only component folder but unable to copy the both. Can someone please help me on this. It would be of immense help. Thank You well in  advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve this.

Configure your `copy` task to one of the following. You *probably* only need to follow *Solution A*.

Note: *Solution A* and *B*, both achieve the same result. *Solution C* achieves a slightly different result:

---

**Solution A**

Using one [target](https://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#task-configuration-and-targets) named `html` you can do this:

```
copy:{
  html:{
    files:[{
      src:['components/**', 'index.html'],
      dest:'build/'
    }]
  }
}
```

Note: In the `src` array above the first item which reads `'components/**'` utilizes a [Globbing pattern](https://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#globbing-patterns) (i.e. the `**` part). This means includes all items from the `components`folder and include all subfolders many levels deep when copying.

---

**Solution B**

Or, using two targets; one named `html` and another named `components` you can do this:

```
copy:{
  html:{
    files:[{
      src:'index.html',
      dest:'build/'
    }]
  },
  components:{
    files:[{
      src:'components/**',
      dest:'build/'
    }]
  }
}
```

This is very similar to *Solution A*, however it uses two targets instead of one, which may be more appropriate as the target names actually indicate what they are copying.

---

**Solution C**

However if you don't actually want the `components` folder to be copied to `build`, and instead you only want the contents of the `components` folder to be copied you can do this:

```
copy:{
  html:{
    files:[{
      src:'index.html',
      dest:'build/'
    }]
  },
  components:{
    files:[{
      expand:true,
      cwd: 'components',
      src:'**',
      dest:'build/'
    }]
  }
}
```

---

**Note:** For additional information refer to the [files](https://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#files) section of the grunt documentation: